# Difference between CoreData and Hibernate

Tags: java, ios, hibernate, core-data

CoreData is explained as a "**schema-driven object graph management and persistence framework**" in iOS mostly used with SQLite as persistence store. Not Necessarily, you could use it for example just in memory without ever saving any of the managed objects into a persistence store like SQLite.

Taking a look at Hibernate it seems to have many similarities whilst I am questioning the key difference between them.

## Schema Driven

CoreData uses a schema, which is mostly (in iOS), an xcdatamodel file containing the entities and so on.

Hibernate doesn't have that graphical editor like xcode for xcdatamodels since I know, but you can use it either with XML files or direct Annotations due to JPA. Both are schemes as well IMHO.

## Object graph management

CoreData manages my objects including change tracking as well as checking my constraints defined in the scheme. Further it supports mechanisms to reduce the memory usage by object faulting and many more.

I think so does Hibernate. It keeps track of the constraints defined in xml or via annotations and supports mechanisms to reduce memory usage like coredata (lazy loading, etc.)

## Persistence

CoreDate uses an underlying database sqlite as persistence store but may used otherwise like in memory as well.

Hibernate uses for example a MySQL db as persistence store but may use an an in memory storage  like coredata (hsqldb-mem)

So due to the fact that I am not a pro with hibernate, I woundering - can you call key concept differences between both are are they really a lot like each other?

Comment: All ORM solutions have many features in common just because they are ORMs. This is pretty much where similarities between Hibernate and CoreData end, however: they have different APIs, different source trees, different languages, different implementation goals, and so on.

Comment: I am asking for key concept differences not any language, api or such kind of differences!!!
A Key difference would be for example if coredata would use an object database (sure it doesn't). I think every child could see that there is a language difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about exact key diff but one of my understanding is

> Core Data is specifically meant for single client usage and just
>   automates model layer, where as Hibernate is meant for multiple client
>   usage (kind of enterprise) and provides much more abstraction and
>   functionality than core data.

Comment: Ah exactly, that's what I found a few minutes ago as well. I'll keep the question up a little bit, maybe there are some more differences!
Otherwise this'll be accepted. Thank you!